# WPF Binding inside Text attribute differs from actual Binding tag syntax in MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

So the issue is that when I normally bind a single text item to the Text in a TextBlock, the syntax is as follows:

```
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding Attributes[StatusDateTime]}" /> //WORKS GREAT!
```

Now, background is that the DataContext for this part of the app is the output of a 3rd party API.  "Attributes" is a collection of KeyValuePair, which is a property of the parent object.  StatusDateTime is the key for the value I am returning.  The syntax above works just great! So the object would look something like: theDataContextObject.Attributes[StatusDateTime].

BUT, if I need to combine multiple attributes into one TextBlock that's when things get hairy.  I have no idea how to access the key from an actual Binding tag:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource popupText}">
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} at {1}">
        <Binding Path="{Attributes[Type]}"/>
        <!--<Binding Path="StatusDateTime" />-->
        <Binding Path=Attributes[Type]/>
        <Binding Path="Type" ElementName="Attributes"/> //the element has no
                                           //name it's just the datacontext
        <Binding Path="[StatusDateTime]" />
        <Binding Path="Attributes[StatusDateTime]"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

I know the number of examples above does not match the stringformat, I was just pasting examples of my guesses into the multibinding of how to get these values bound.

Apologies if this is a duplicate with another question.  I am not sure what to even call this kind of binding where I'm just passing Attributes[StatusDateTime] directly to binding.  Keep in mind that Attributes is not the name of an object, it's a property of the object passed to datacontext of the TextBlock's parent control.

So how do I bind to the value of key in the KeyValuePair collection when i have to use a Binding tag inside a MultiBinding?